# How to create a trigger to increment a column when that row is updated?

Tags: mysql, triggers

[image: database]

Every time a row of this table is updated, the 'level' cell of that row must be incremented by 1. Is there a trigger that can help with this?

Comment: Why not increment as part of the update?

Comment: I did that but my project which is in PHP, is giving some errors so I thought of using triggers to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_level
BEFORE UPDATE
ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.level = OLD.level + 1;
```

> Is it possible to add an if loop which will check whether the status is ongoing or finished and the trigger level should only increment if status is ongoing?

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_level
BEFORE UPDATE
ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.level = OLD.level + (NEW.status = 'ongoing');
```

Comment: Hey Akina, thank you so much! This is working great but it's giving some other issues. Is it possible to add an if loop which will check whether the status is ongoing or finished and the trigger level should only increment if status is ongoing?
Thanks again!

Comment: @RahulMehta Easily. Added.